# OS-X: Compile commands having problems with colons

Tags: python, bash, macos, gcc

Recently, I turned on an old laptop and have been using it for doing some python development. A lot of pip commands call gcc or similar under the hood. Take the following for example, though I  have seen the same error on a variety of similar commands, not just gcc:

```
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/foo/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/foo/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include:-I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include : -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=572 -DPSUTIL_OSX=1 -I/Users/foo/.local/pipx/venvs/mylib/include -I/Users/foo/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/psutil/_psutil_common.o
```

Will give the following error:

```
  gcc: error: :: No such file or directory
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Unfortunately, the error statement is hard to google. I know that that I was able to compile with gcc / build python libraries no problem previously, but I must have messed something up, reading the error, somehow broke how the shell handles colons? Or maybe gcc / the compiler version changed and broke how these lines are read. I'd appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of the command is wrong:

```
-I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include:-I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include :
```

You don't specify multiple directories separated by `:`, you use separate `-I` options. And you have a lone `:` after the two `-I` options, which is being taken as a filename.

That part of the command should be:

```
-I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include -I/usr/local/opt/openjdk/include
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, this is a command that is coming via pip, not made by me. Maybe some environment variable is broken leading to this bad command?

Comment: OK- i think I've found the culprit: in my bashrc, I have several lines extending `$CPPFLAGS`. If i simply comment those out and reset, the build is successful. I'm not exactly sure what the modifications are from (it's been a while since I used this lappy and some may be auto generated) but this is a good promising start.